# IOS: drag and drop from a tableView VS scrollview

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uiscrollview, drag-and-drop

In my app I should to use some imageViews to drag and drop them in other position; the problem is that I have 30 imageView and I sould put them inside a scrollView or a tableview because they don't entry all in my firts view. 
Then my question, is better to put these imageViews inside a scrollView or in a tableview?

Comment: Scroll view would prove better approach for as far as my experience says.

Answer (score 1):

by using the touches began,touches moved,touches ended method you can do that.